# Why use traits?

Tags: rust, traits, conceptual

What typical scenario would traits be used for in a Rust program? I have tried to wrap my head around them, but I still don't have a clear *concept* as to why one would decide to use them. I understand the syntax from reading about them from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait.html).

How would one explain them to someone as if they were 5?

Comment: Are you talking about traits or structs?

Comment: uh! i am talking about traits, i just used structs from C as a casual example to illustrate a conceptual view of it but it's not really connected to the question

Comment: Honestly, because you can’t not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to conceptualize traits is to think of them as 'behaviors you want available to, and to operate over, a particular chunk of state'. So, if you have some struct that contains state, and you want to do something with it, you would write a trait for it.

There are two primary usages:

- You are dealing with a struct in your code, and you would like that struct to know how perform some behavior. You can call the trait-defined behavior on the struct.
- You would like to pass the struct to some other code (yours or a third party) that might not know anything about the struct itself, but want to perform some set of functions on it, trusting that the struct knows what to do in those cases.

In the first case, it allows you to do things like this:

```
struct Article {
  body: String
}

trait Saveable {
  fn save(&self) -> ();
}

impl Saveable for Article {
  fn save(&self) -> () {
    ...  // All the code you need to run to save the Article object
  }
} 

// A function called by your UX
fn handle_article_update(article: Article) -> () {
  ...
  article.save()  // Call the save functionality
}
```

The second case is arguably more interesting, though. Let's say you - or more probably a third party - has a function defined like this:

```
fn save_object(obj: Saveable) -> () {
  ...
  obj.save()
}

struct Person {
  name: String
}

impl Saveable for Person {
  fn save(&self) -> () {
    ... // Code needed to save a Person object, could be different from that needed for an Article object
  }
}

...
// Note that we are using the same function to save both of these, despite being different underlying Structs
save_object(article)
save_object(person)
```

What this means is that the `save_object` function does not need to know anything about your custom `Article` struct in order to call `save` on it. It can simply refer to your implementation of that method in order to do so. In this way you can write custom objects that third party or generic library functions are able to act upon, because the `Trait` has defined a set of behaviors with a contract that the code can rely on safely.

Then the question of, 'when do you want to use a Trait' can be answered by saying: whenever you want to use behavior defined on a struct without needing to know everything about the struct - just that it has that behavior. So, in the above, you might also have an 'edit' functionality attached to `Article`, but not to `Person`. You don't want to have to change `save_object` to account for this, or to even care. All `save_object` needs to know is that the functions defined in the `Saveable` trait are implemented - it doesn't need to know anything else about the object to function equally well.

Another way to phrase this is to say, 'Use a trait when you want to pass an object based on what it can do, not what it is.'

Comment: I don't get it. What is the purpose of first case? You could just ```impl Article { fn save(&self) {...} }``` and use it as `article.save()` anywhere without creating any traits.

Comment: @Dmitry You can, though that means two things: you have to use `Article` as the type a function accepts, and your `save()` function is not equivalent to one implemented by `Saveable`. If `Saveable` is provided by another library, your `Article` won't work with it. (A more salient example of this is the `Display` trait.) That said, the first case here is largely explanatory, it's the second case that makes traits really worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html):

> A `trait` is a collection of methods defined for an unknown type: `Self`. They can access other methods declared in the same trait.

Traits are similar to interfaces in languages like Java, C++, etc.

It would really be helpful to go over examples, such as the [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) and the [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) traits.

If you write this:

```
format!("x is {x}");
```

the code will only work (and compile) if `x` *implements* the `Display` interface.

Similarly, this will only work if `x` *implements* the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) interface:

```
format!("{x:?}");
```

Leaving aside the "magic" associated with formatting strings, it should be clear `x` cannot be an instance of just *any* type. There needs to be a specific *implementation* that converts a given type to a string. Note that `u16`'s implementation, for example, would be completely different from, say, `IpAddr`'s implementation. However, both types have a common behavior. As a result, a string formatter doesn't even need to know which types implement the `Display` or `Debug` trait. It's not its concern. It only cares whether the type in question implements the given trait (and if it does not, the compiler simply won't accept that code).

Comment: so one would use traits in case their goal is common behavior for certain types, am I right?